# Neo4j webadmin panel not opening

Tags: neo4j

I downloaded neo4j community version for linux and installed successfully. The neo4j server is also running. i am not able to open web admin panel

```
(http://localhost:7474/webadmin/).
```

I searched for answers in google groups and stack overflow and uncommented the

```
    org.neo4j.server.webserver.address =0.0.0.0
```

line in neo4j.server.properties file. But still i am not able to connect to webadmin panel. I am stuck in it. Any help would be appreciated. Dont mark it as duplicate and ignore it as i have referred all the previous questions on this.

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://localhost:7474/webadmin/` in your browser?
The line you uncommented is only relevant if you are running the server on a different machine from the on you use to connect. If you are, you need to substitute that machine's IP address for `localhost`.

Comment: It says Google chrome could not connect to http://localhost:7474

Comment: Assuming you started the server something like `$ bin/neo4j start`, could you post the feedback?

Comment: WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

Comment: Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [6550]... waiting for server to be ready......... OK.
Go to http://localhost:7474/webadmin/ for administration interface.

Comment: Any suggestions please..

Comment: The server starts alright, anything in the Neo4j logs? If there's a network problem I'm not the person to help, sorry. You could try using explicit IP or loopback, for instance `127.0.0.1:7474`, or a different browser. Some recent version of Chrome apparently had problems resolving `localhost`.

Comment: It's opening. Thanks for the replies @jjaderberg..

Comment: Great, can you share how you got it to work?

Comment: I really dont know , Yest night i left it undone , Today morning I did all the steps for installation again , It opened , even i am surprised..haha..